# Why is electricity transmitted at high voltage?

Tags: transformer, transmission-line

I've learnt that step-up transformers are used to increase voltage and hence decrease current so we can reduce power losses in transmission.

If the product V * I is constant with or without a transformer then how is it reducing the power lost?

If the resistance of the load connected across the secondary is fixed then the current we need to pass through it to get a certain amount of power is also fixed. How does increasing the voltage help?

Comment: Power losses in the transmission of electrical energy along power lines must be reduced. To do this as P=VI=RI², from which it can be deduced that the lower the current the lower the power dissipated along the line due to the Joule effect. For the same power on the line, it is better to have high voltages and low currents.

Answer (score 2):

VI is the power transmitted The power lost in the lines is I^2R, R is the resistance of the lines. The high voltage means that I can be reduced for the same amount of power transmitted, reducing I reduces power losses as a square law of I.

You use a transformer at both ends of the lines e.g you generate at 100V you transmit the power at 10kV then you convert it back down to 100V for use at the load.
[image]

Comment: In the first picture the total resistance is 14 ohm while the supply voltage is 100 V so how is the current 10 A? Similarly in th second picture the stepped up voltage is 10,000 V and the resistance is 4 ohm so how can the current be 0.1 A?

Comment: The supply states supply 100V to load so in this case it would need to be 140V the 40V will be lost in the lines. You are not dropping the 10kV over 4 Ohms the current is determined by the transformer.

Comment: Thank you I understand the first case but I'm still a bit confused how in the second case we achieved 10,000 V and 0.1 A

Comment: With the use of the transformers. A transformer has the same power out as power in (ignoring losses) so VI in = VI out. 100x10=10000x0.1

Comment: But using ohm's law we would get that the resistance in the circuit is V/I which is much more than the first case. How are we able to change these parameters without changing the resistance of the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

You could transmit electricity at low voltage with the same losses simply by using fatter wires so the losses in the wires were the same. That would avoid the transformers.

However the cost of many km of fat wire will quickly exceed the cost of step-up and step-down transformers.

There are also reactive losses due to using AC, and for some kinds of transmission it's worth it to convert the AC to very high voltage DC (like 800kV) and back again at the other end. That requires a large amount of equipment such as thyristors, IGBTs (or in the old days, mercury arc tubes).